# Stop lead assignment notification. .setSendNotificationEmail(false); use?

Tags: email

In our instance, all leads are assigned to a queue, and are never assigned to a user until they are converted (and this is only done because queues can not own the account). The owner is changed through a trigger, and this causes an email to be sent out. How do I stop the email from being sent? The documentation I have read shows .setSendNotificationEmail is the path for this, however, they have not stopped. We have no assignment rules, so we know this is not an issue. Code snippet where this is firing is below. Thank you in advance for your time.

```
else
        { 
            Database.LeadConvert convLead = new Database.LeadConvert();
            convLead.setOwnerId(UserInfo.getUserId());
            convLead.setSendNotificationEmail(false);
            convLead.setLeadId(applicant.Id);
            convLead.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus);
            convLead.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
            leadList.add(convLead);
        }
```

Comment: Is there a workflow rule thats firing and sending the mail instead ?

Comment: Nope, no workflow rule, no email alert set up to fire on the lead object, or any other.

Comment: (1) if you look at the debug log, can you tell at which step of the lead conversion process the email is sent?  Lots of stuff happens on lead conversion - notably account and contact triggers and possible workflows.  (2) The structure of the email can indicate its source.